# How can I get the values of some part of a json string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api

I'm working with this Json structure, but I don't know how to get the values of the part of the "json" key

I'm using this code to send a request to an API, and the return is an Json object:

```cs
var reqData = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://server_ip/system/message/date/{0}/", txtDate.Text));
            reqData.ContentType = "application/json";
            reqData.Method = "GET";


var answer = (HttpWebResponse)reqData.GetResponse();
List<Dictionary<string, string>> convert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(answer);
```

The result is a Json structure like this:

```
"[
  {
   \"idMessage\":\"--Message Id--",
   \"idTemplate\":--TemplateId--,
   \"mail\":\"--mail dir--\",
   \"subject\":\"--message subject--\",
    \"json\":\"{
                \\\"Id\\\":\\\"--Person Id--\\\",
                \\\"name\\\":\\\"--Person name--\\\",
                \\\"date\\":\\\"--Register date-\\\",
                \\\"hour\\\":\\\"--Register hour--\\\"
               }\",
    \"senddate\":\"--sent date--\",
    \"status\":0,
    \"template\":null
   }
  ]"
```

I want to get the values (`Id,name,date,hour`) from the json part of this Json string, can someone help me to get this values?

Comment: The JSON in your question is not well-formed -- it seems to have some string escaping possibly added by a debugger or JSON visualization tool.  Can you please [edit] your question to share the raw JSON without escaping?  As it is, the escaping is inconsistent; e.g. in `\"idMessage\":\"--Message Id--"` the final '"' character seems not to be escaped, making it hard to test your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `json` property contains a string of more JSON, so you have to deserialize that again, the same way you did the whole outer structure.

So now that you have your `convert` array, you can pull out the first object, grab the value of `json` and deserialize that:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(convert[0]["json"]);
```

Then you can pull each value out like this:

```
var id = json["Id"];
```

Mind you, the JSON in your question isn't actually valid. There are a few errors in it. But I'm assuming that they're just copy/paste errors and the web service is actually returning valid JSON.